# pyspark keep only one type of group

Tags: pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I want to do a check on the distinct name count on the same group, and I only want to keep one name in this group.

```
df.groupBy('job','age','gender').agg(countDistinct('name')).filter('count(DISTINCT name)>1').show()
```

| job | age | gender | count(DISTINCT name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| engineer | 22 | M | 3 |

Then I want to go to this group, to keep only one of the name. Let's say when we go to this group, we have something like this:

| job | age | gender | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| engineer | 22 | M | John | 10 |
| engineer | 22 | M | Leo | 15 |
| engineer | 22 | M | Leo | 16 |
| engineer | 22 | M | Mike | 17 |
| engineer | 22 | M | Mike | 19 |

And then, I want to keep Mike only (drop John and Leo in this group)
So I want the group to be like this

| job | age | gender | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| engineer | 22 | M | Mike | 17 |
| engineer | 22 | M | Mike | 19 |

How to use a function in pyspark to implement this? So that I can apply this function in different df? Thanks

Comment: Do you care who to be picked?

Comment: In term of who to be picked, I would like the name on the latest(last) row.

Comment: how do you identify which row is last? spark does not retain a dataframe's ordering (due to it's distributed nature). the last row in an instance may not be the same as in another instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank` window function.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('job', 'age', 'gender').orderBy(desc('name'))
df = (df.withColumn('rnk', rank().over(w))
      .filter(col('rnk') == 1))
```